# Recursive relations - list people with a supervisor and those without a supervisor

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got an official table, with id and name....

Officials may have supervisors - these are stored in a join table called officialsupervisor with official_id and supervisor_id as foreign keys to the official table.

I can show officials with their supervisor with

```
SELECT o.official_name Official, p.official_name Supervisor 
FROM officialsupervisor s, official o, official p 
WHERE o.official_id = s.official_id AND p.official_id = s.supervisor_official_id
```

I can list officials that don't have a supervisor with

```
 SELECT o.official_name Official
 FROM  official o
 WHERE o.official_id NOT IN (SELECT official_id
 FROM officialsupervisor)
```

But I can't work out how to list all officials with their supervisor, or a blank if they don't have one.  I feel as though this should be quite straightforward!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this once:

```
SELECT o.official_name Official, p.official_name Supervisor
FROM official o
LEFT JOIN officialsupervisor s ON o.official_id = s.official_id
LEFT JOIN official p ON p.official_id = s.supervisor_official_id
```

Comment: Thank you - this works perfectly.  Looking it up, I see that LEFT JOIN is the same as LEFT OUTER join, so it's using the same technique the other answer tried to use.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need recursive query all you need is to join the two tables with [`OUTER JOINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx):

```
SELECT o.official_name Official, p.officialname  
FROM officialsupervisor s
Left Outer Join official o on o.official_id = s.official_id 
Left Outer JOIN official p ON p.official_id = s.supervisor_official_id
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it doesn't work.  I've spotted one type - the first line should have `p.official_name`.  But even changing that, I get the error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Comment: I'm guessing it's the trailing comma after the table alias in the FROM clause.

Comment: Now it runs, but it still doesn't list the officials that don't have a supervisor.  I think because the left join is on officialsupervisor, which does not list all the officials, only those that have a supervisor.

Thanks for the link - helped me understand what is going on.